# How to setup Jenkins to use Knife in a Powershell script

Tags: powershell, jenkins, chef-infra, knife

I am using Jenkins on a Windows Server 2012 R2. I would like to run a job that builds, and on forced promotion it should tell the remote chef server that the recipe has changed or updated then start the chef-client on the remote nodes.

I have installed the Chef Identity Plugin, Promoted-builds Plugin, MSbuild Plugin, TFS-4.0.0 plugin and the Deploy Plugin

So far the build works and the promotions work. 
I have set up on forced promotion that two Powershell scripts should run. 
The first one works fine, it does just basic data management and file naming.

But the second one says it was a failure but the promotion still passes and there is no evidence that is worked at all.

I have explicitly used the path to Knife because when I don't use it, Jenkins gives an error of:

```
WARNING: No knife configuration file found
ERROR: Could not find cookbook MyFirstCookingLesson in your cookbook path, skipping it
ERROR: ArgumentError: Cannot sign the request without a client name, check that :node_name is assigned
```

If I add the -V flag and run the script by right clicking it and running it with Powershell in Jenkins workspace I get this Information:

[image]

The ps1 file contains (Lets call it 'Chef-client.ps1'):

```
C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\knife cookbook upload MyFirstCookingLesson
C:\opscode\chefdk\bin\knife job start 'chef-client' WIN-COMPNAME
```

The Chef-client.ps1 is called using the Execute Windows Batch Command:

```
cd C:\chef-source\cookbooks
PowerShell.exe -File  C:\chef-source\cookbooks\Chef-client.ps1
```

I have also set up the Chef identity in the Jenkins credentials as follows:

```
Identity name: geoff
user.pem key : <a whole bunch of secret stuffs and gibberish>

knife.rb : 

log_level :info
log_location STDOUT
node_name 'geoff'
client_key 'C:/Users/user123/.chef/geoff.pem'
validation_client_name  'geoff.pem'
validation_key 'C:/Users/user123/.chef/secretName-validator.pem'
chef_server_url 'https://secretLocation.268lab.local/organizations/secretName/'
syntax_check_cache_path 'C:/Users/user123/.chef/syntax_check_cache'
cookbook_path [ 'c:/chef-source/cookbooks/' ]
http_proxy 'http://22.151.32.85:3128'
https_proxy 'http://22.151.32.85:3128'
no_proxy 'secretLocation.268lab.local'
knife[:editor] = '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"';
```

So I have also found out that Jenkins seems to run in its own Userprofile which I have a feeling might be throwing everything off.

I have read over so many set up blogs but nothing that really tells me how to set this up explicitly. The blogs either just assume its done already or uses a different tool.

I also placed copies of the .chef folder in both the Jenkins Workspace and the 'hopeful' Userprofile space in hopes that it would work.

Please could anyone help guide me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment:

> So I have also found out that Jenkins seems to run in its own
>   Userprofile which I have a feeling might be throwing everything off.

If your jenkins user can't read user123 home, there's no chance it can read the knife config not properly authenticate as it can't read the geoff.pem file.

One solution to get around this problem is to put the config, keys etc in a specific directory and using the `-c` option of knife to give it the path to the conf file. Another option is using the `KNIFE_HOME` environment variable but it's less easy and error prone in Jenkins.

Comment: Sorry about that. I have moved the error message up for better reading. I assume that the -vv isn't a (double u) and its suppose to be a -V? if I use -vv it succeeds and if I use a -W it says it isn't a valid parameter.

Comment: Doubling the V cause knife to be more verbose, my point is that you show us an error which you say you have fixed, which does not sound useful to help you

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. That error message is the one that I'm getting from the second script I'm running. It complains that there is no Knife configuration file.

Comment: In this case the first part if my answer give it, it's a permission problem of the Jenkins user to access the file in another user home dir.

Comment: Okay cools. So that means I'm working on the correct track. Bu would you happen to know how to solve that?

Would I have to place the chef files in the Jenkins userprofile or more like configure Jenkins to be able to access the other users home dir?

Comment: Personnaly I use a specific directory and pass the path to knife with -c option (this allow me to have two config for dev and prod orgs too)

Comment: Okay fantastic. I am getting somewhere. -c seems to work for my upload command. But Knife job start seems to fail. But thank you very much for your help so far! :)

Comment: I'm not using push jobs addon, so can't really help there, but as it's a knife plugin same advices should work.

Comment: Would you like to add, in your  answer, that I should use the -c option and then I'll accept it as an answer?

Comment: @DeanMarsden done, and stripped the last part as we did clear out the problem about the error message.